# Define custom colors in visual studio?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, rgb

In visual studio I can type "blue" in a CSS value for instance and it will translate it to the appropriate RGB.   Is it possible to define custom colors?  I'd love to be able to define "companyBlue" or "companyOrange".

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but have a look at http://lesscss.org/. It gives you variables.

Comment: Interesting. It says something about rhino, node.js or client-side in modern browsers only.  What does that mean, exactly?  If all my users are on IE8 or above, is there any setup or prerequisites?

Comment: To answer my own question above, now that I'm a noob++ that's just for compiling the LESS to CSS.  Many IDEs have plugins to do it for you automatically, on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a `CSS` file then you shouldn't be using any colornames like `Blue`, `Green`,... Because browsers decide for themselves which color value they give to these colors. The color `Green` might be a completely different color in IE when comparing to Google Chrome.

I'd recommand using hex values instead like:

```
#000 /* Black */
#fff /* White */
#f00 /* Red */
```

You can easily get hex values, with this photoshop-like color selector: http://www.2createawebsite.com/build/hex-colors.html

Now, back to your original question, how can you use variablese like `companyOrange` in CSS? Simply put... with only CSS you cannot use any variables. You however can "store" the value at the top of your CSS file in a comment like so:

```
/*
    COLORS
    Black:          #000    
    Company Orange: #f64;
    Company grey:   #444;
*/
```

If you really want to use variables instead, you can use a CSS pre-processesor such as SASS, LESS, Stylus,... All of these use variables.

**Read more:**

- http://sass-lang.com/
- http://lesscss.org/
- http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/

Comment: Actually, some colors *are* defined as corresponding to specific values:  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4.  Unofficial colors (cornflowerblue, mediumaquamarine, etc.) are supported by just about every browser.  It's generally better not to use them since most names are longer than 7 characters:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names

Comment: @cimmanon That's just the spec, it's up to the browsers to follow it but they can use any hex value they want?

Comment: That's kinda what the spec is for, to tell browser developers what needs to be implemented and how.

Comment: True, but yet browser developers fail to follow the spec correctly, that's why a website might look different in IE compared to Chrome. :)

Comment: For the record, I ended up using LESS and falling in love with it.  I never leave home without it now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, but don't really love the solution: http://24ways.org/2006/faster-development-with-css-constants/

> To truly achieve constants you will need to use something other than
>   CSS to process the file before it is sent to the browser. You can use
>   any scripting language – PHP, ASP, ColdFusion etc. to parse a CSS file
>   in which you have entered constants. So that in a constants section of
>   the CSS file you would have:
>
> ```
> $darkgrey = '#333333'; 
> $darkblue = '#000066';
> ```
>
> The rest of the CSS file
>   is as normal except that when you come to use the constant value you
>   would use the constant name instead of adding the color:
>
> ```
> p { color: $darkgrey; }
> ```
>
> Your server-side script could then parse the
>   CSS file, replace the constant names with the constant values and
>   serve a valid CSS file to the browser. Christian Heilmann has done
>   just this for PHP however this could be adapted for any language you
>   might have available on your server.
>
> Shaun Inman came up with another way of doing this that removes the
>   need to link to a PHP script and also enables the adding of constants
>   using the syntax of at-rules . This method is again using PHP and will
>   require you to edit an .htaccess file.
>
> A further method is to generate static CSS files either using a script
>   locally – if the constants are just to enable speed of development –
>   or as part of the web application itself. Storing a template
>   stylesheet with constant names in place of the values you will want to
>   update means that your script can simply open the template, replace
>   the variables and save the result as a new stylesheet file.
>
> While CSS constants are a real help to developers, they can also be
>   used to add new functionality to your applications. As with the email
>   address example that I used at the beginning of this article, using a
>   combination of CSS and server-side scripting you could enable a site
>   administrator to select the colours for a new theme to be used on a
>   page of a content managed site. By using constants you need only give
>   them the option to change certain parts of the CSS and not upload a
>   whole different CSS file, which could lead to some interesting
>   results!
>
> As we are unlikely to find real CSS constants under the tree this
>   Christmas the above methods are some possibilities for better
>   management of your stylesheets. However if you have better methods,
>   CSS Constant horror stories or any other suggestions, add your
>   comments below.

Comment: Most probably the OP is not using a CSS file but simply adding the colors with the properties of each element.

Comment: I am the OP and I am using a CSS file ;)